# AJAX returned data - how to treat them with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

So when jQuery makes an `$.ajax` request, the returned data can be handled with the `success` function attribute (a function) of the object passed as a parameters to `$.ajax`. As the [API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) report, if the `processData` attribute is set to `true`, the data will be returned as a string, otherwise as a DOM object (is that right?).

So, I need to treat the data as if they were simple HTML. Let's say I have to prepend and append a series of `=`s to every `h1` tag in the returned data, and then fill a page with those data as if they were a plain string (in order to use the jQuery `.html()` method).

What's the correct way to do it?

I found that the `.parseHTML()` jQuery function could be useful in order to parse the returned data string into HTML DOM. But how do I treat it?

Sorry for some lack of *what have you tried* in this question.

#### Edit

Someone suggested a more clear example. I have a `.html` file with some content I want to retrieve through AJAX and use to fill my main page content. This file is structured as simple HTML, without `head`/`body` tags, just some `p`s and a few `h1`s. Through CSS I already made `h1` tags look exactly like `p`s (which is intended).
Now I want to transform this:

```
<h1>I'm a simple header</h1>
```

into plain text this:

```
===================
I'm a simple header
===================
```

kind of Unix terminal style.

Comment: processData, not progressData

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're trying to do with your input. Are you trying to turn `<h1>` into `<h1 id="something">` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** The below is working perfectly for me

**File1.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({  
    url: 'http://voicing-up.com/test.html',  
        success: function(data) {  
                alert(data);
            alert($(data).html());
        }  
    });
});
</script>
```

**Test.html**

```
<p>This is some data</p>
<h2>This is h2</h2
```

In the code above, data is going to return DOM elements, and from there you can use jQuery's `.html()` function to get the innerHTML of the element.

Comment: Being `data` a plain string, `$(data)` raises a `Syntax error: unrecognized expression`.

Comment: @whatyouhide I have it working on my server, perfectly. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue related to how my HTML retrieved file is formatted. Let me try some stuff and I'll let you know.

Comment: I have no formatting in mine, just the raw html tags - no headers or anything like that.

Comment: @whatyouhide Do an alert on data, just to see what `data` is returning for you

Comment: Yep, it was a formatting problem (I had some free text, not wrapped in tags). Now I can parse the HTML through jQuery, though `$(data).find('h1')` still returns `prevObject...`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26832/discussion-between-evan-and-whatyouhide)